# Реализовать метод для формирования массива строк из строки с разделителем используя класс java.util.Scanner без использование split

Tags: java

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(",");
String s = sc.nextLine().trim();
int k =1; 

for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if(s.charAt(i) == ',') {
        k++;
    }
}
String[] arr = new String[k];
```

нашел длину нужного массива, но не могу заполнить его

Answer (score 3):

Пожалуйста, без `split`. Сейчас скажете что и без `StringTokenizer`

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(scanner.nextLine());
String[] stringArray = new String[st.countTokens()];
int k = 0;
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    stringArray[k++] = st.nextToken();
}
```

P.S.
Если ваш преподаватель хочет чтобы вы все сделали руками - `split` только для whitespace или знаков препинания реализуется тривиально.

**UPD**

Разделитель `,`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(scanner.nextLine(), ",");
String[] stringArray = new String[st.countTokens()];
int k = 0;
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    stringArray[k++] = st.nextToken();
}
Stream.of(stringArray).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Input:

> This,is,a,test

Output:

> This
>
> is
>
> a
>
> test

Comment: если у нас есть строка (This,is,a,test) то этот метод не вставляет сразу всю строку в первый элемент массива ?

Comment: У `StringTokenizer` есть параметр `delimeter` куда вы можете указать любой разделитель или строку из разделителей. По умолчанию, если разделитель не указать, используется строка из `" \t\n\r\f"` Обновил ответ.

Comment: Вот  этого низнал спасибо !!!